# Turn image into geometric array of colours

Tags: software-recommendation, effects, filter

Is there a tool like [Poly (iPad app)](http://itunes.apple.com/ca/app/poly/id477351128?mt=8) available for Android or Windows systems? I'd like to  turn images into polygones/triangles like shown on the app site.

[image]

Answer (score 15):

Did a little poking around...turns out that Poly uses something called [Delaunay Triangulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delaunay_triangulation). If you search around for that term, some stuff comes up.

---

[This guy (Jonathan Puckey)](http://jonathanpuckey.com/projects/delaunay-raster/) claims to pretty much own the process, but [these guys (createtogether)](http://www.creatogether.com/downloads/delaunay-brush/) would disagree - they've created a brush in Illustrator that lets you create something similar. I've not tried it personally but it might work for you. This, and Jonathan Puckey's process, are both based on the [Scriptographer plugin](http://scriptographer.org/) for Adobe Illustrator.

[image]

---

If you're into Processing, [the plugin Mesh by Lee Byron](http://leebyron.com/else/mesh/) generates the lines from the points:

[image]

---

Also found this [filter](http://www.filterforge.com/filters/223.html) for Photoshop that seems to polygon-ize things, but it probably isn't quite what you're looking for. There is the stained glass and mosaic filters in PS as well! But those are pretty lame in comparison to Poly.

[image]

---

If this doesn't answer your question, hope it at least points you in the right direction!

Comment: I find it hilarious that a person can claim to "invent a technique" in 2008 that I did in freshman 2d art by hand in 1988 (and my teachers had been using as a teaching aid for 40 years)

Comment: @horatio I thought it was an odd claim too. You undoubtedly know more about this than I do...anything to add to this? I'm interested in learning more about the technique.

Comment: The basic is that you overlay a grid on the image and then make a decision about the overall color value of the square. The human equivalent of "averaging" the colors is usually called "squinting." You limit your palette as well to make it manageable, and you premix pots of those colors. Then you make comparisons cell-by-cell and choose the proper color, and then you fill the grid. It is a mechanical process. The "plugin mesh" shown above can be thought of as a deformed grid. In one case, I had to grid up my signature, enlarge it by hand, and then deform the grid and re-render it. In ink.

Comment: Note that in this particular case, the non-rectangular grid allows one to identify large contrast changes as the basis for the primary points. This probably is better for curves.

Answer (score 7):

You can use an online tool like [this triangulation tool](http://snorpey.github.io/triangulation/) or [this Delaunay triangulations tool](http://labs.vieron.net/delaunay-triangulations/) with images that you upload.

[image: Lincoln triangulated]

Another option is [Kubist](http://williamngan.github.io/kubist/), another online tool that does pretty much the same thing.

An even more robust option that outputs similar images, allows you to use rectangles, circles, or triangles, and export to PNG, JPG, SVG, or GIF is [Primitive](https://github.com/fogleman/primitive), an open source project.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Adobe Photoshop you can also use an action called `Low Poly` by psd-dude, you can grab it from his official site [here](http://www.psd-dude.com/tutorials/resources/low-poly-photoshop-free-action.aspx). (You do have to sign up and there are lots of ads on the site, be warned).

[image: low poly action]

or if you want some more PRO Action you can also use [Low Poly Generator](http://graphicriver.net/item/low-poly-generator-photoshop-actions/10647683)

[image]

Answer (score -4):

I've just implemented a Delaunay effect in my app Glitch! for Android:
You can download here: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lucagrillo.ImageGlitcher

[image]

Comment: Is this your app?  This also sounds like spam.  If you are affiliated with the app you must mention that in your profile and answer.

Comment: Although self promotion isn't explicitly prohibited, it doesn't look like the app gives enough control over the effect to achieve what the question is asking. Without any more details, the answer does look like spammy self promotion.

Comment: Yes, i'm the creator of the app (just check my name L.Grillo in the Google play page).

Comment: Although, if i can read well, the question was: "Is there a tool like Poly (iPad app) available for Android or Windows systems?"  And in which other way should i can answer to this??? you are ridicolous!

Comment: It's not ridiculous. From your answer I still have no idea what specifically your app does in regard to this effect. A good answer would be to list the steps needed to recreate what the question asked for with screenshots and explanations of the different options and results. At the minute the answer is a link and an image of what looks like an ad for the app. I would have to download the app before knowing if it does what I want.