# How do you make random 'diamond' design in Photoshop?

Tags: texture

How do you create random diamond, crystal design like this ad on Photoshop? Could anybody please teach me and also identify what's the proper name for design like this call? Thanks a lot!

[image: http://img12.imageshack.us/img12/9615/90316452075115463091215.jpg]

^Check out the picture design that I'm talking about here. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a pretty random form of triangulation. Probably just done by hand.

Just draw a bunch of dots and start making triangles to connect the dots!

Awhile back we talked about [Delaunay triangulation](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/10656/5489) on GD.SE...it's a lot more mathematically rigid than the picture you reference but it creates a very similar effect. There are some tools available to make it happen in Illustrator, or you could create your own script to do it yourself (I've done this in a rudimentary way so I can definitely say it's possible). Not sure about doing the same thing in Photoshop, though.

Answer (score 0):

There is no automated method to accomplish this which I'm aware of.

You would need to manually create the shapes, then adjust their fill, stroke, and opacity.