# How do I convert an image to flat-shaded polygons?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I am looking for a way to convert an image into a flat-shaded polygonal mesh. This consists of two steps:

1. Creating the mesh (manually), overlaying an existing image.
2. Shading the mesh (automatically) automatically according to the colors contained within the image.

This should give a look similar to a flat-shaded low-poly 3D rendering. The result would preferably be a vector graphic (prerferably Illustrator, but Inkscape would do, too)

**Question:** How do I best create the mesh, allowing for additional manipulation later on, and is it possible to automatically shade it?

A workflow like for creating gradient meshes would be fine (except that I do want only polygons and no gradients).

## Example

I hope to achieve a look similar to what is shown in the lower right of this image: 
[image]

## Algorithmic thoughts

Most likely just taking the average pixel value below a polygon is what would give me the desired effect after the mesh has been created.

Comment: Similar question: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/10656/turn-image-into-geometric-array-of-colours

Comment: These emulate 3D wireframing, so the ideal solution is to use an actual 3D model. Barring that, I'd suggest just turning on 'snap to corner' in your vector-illustration tool of choice and make a bunch of triangles.

Comment: ̋@Joonas Thanks, even if this is not very helpful unless I downgrade to 5.5 and limit myself to triangles (which wouldn't be too bad).
@DA01 This is what I'll probably go with for now, combined with manually sampling some average color for the polygons.