# How would Forbes' design team create these photos?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, images, effects

There's a gallery of [The Best Advestment Advice of All Time](http://www.forbes.com/pictures/ffgh45eedlh/jack-bogle-2/) where all of the portraits have the same effect applied. What would that be called, and how can I do something similar using Adobe Photoshop?

For example:

[image]

Comment: "Scroll down to the slide show" is horribly misleading on a page which has infinite scrolling. No idea where the slideshow is.. or what images you are referring to.

Comment: [This question](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/10656/5489) isn't exactly what you're going for, but it might help point you in the right direction.

Comment: Sorry about that. Thanks for the tutorial by the way, it takes so much time and effort. Going to try it!

Comment: Welcome to GD..  I closed your question as a dup based ob your title because we already have a geometric shape question. If at any point you have another question regarding it please edit this with an explanation of what you're gaving issues with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a tutorial on the [low-poly portrait effect](http://www.digitalartsonline.co.uk/tutorials/adobe-illustrator/create-low-poly-portrait/)

Comment: Thanks for this but on this website we try to have self-contained answers. If that link goes dead this won't be useful. If you want to summarize what the tutorial says or leave it as a comment, that would be preferred.

Comment: Thanks. I don't have the ability to leave comments yet.

Comment: Welcome to GD!!  Though your answer may help the OP please edit it to include detains about the tutorial and what is going on.  We request that because if your link were ever to yo down from a dead site we will have to delete your answer and then your answer wouldnt help anyone in the future.