# Pattern Name Identification

Tags: patterns, style-identification

After quite a lot of search attempts I failed to find a pattern which we can fill in background so as to generate the background as shown in the graphic below.
I'm not sure if its a pattern or a wallpaper created from scratch. If its a pattern, where can I find one and what keyword shall I google.

[image]

Comment: do you mean the grey folded / creased / scrunched-up paper effect? or the pattern on the photo?

Comment: it's just an abstract bunch of triangles.

Comment: "Polygon background pattern"

Answer (score 2):

I would search for anything relating to crystals or crystalized patterns.  Try mixing terms, maybe add "abstract, background, wallpaper, patter, etc."

[This one](http://www.shutterstock.com/pic-94322254/stock-photo-diamond-seamless-geometric-pattern-abstract-polygon-texture.html) is very close, maybe search for related ones and hopefully find a free one.

I found the above pattern by searching "diamond abstract pattern"

Answer (score 2):

Delaunay Triangulation is a great search term. [We had a discussion about it awhile back](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/10661/5489).

I created a script in [Processing](http://processing.org/) that would fill a rectangle with dots, make Delaunay triangles out of the dots, and then fill the color by putting an image behind the dots, getting the center of each triangle, sampling the pixel behind that center dot, and then filling in the triangle with that color.

You can draw that stuff manually, but Delaunay is a great way to encourage randomness but have rules at the same time so you get predictable results.

Answer (score 0):

## White Geometric Background

[Google Image Link](https://www.google.es/search?q=white%20geometric%20background%20-site:dreamstime.com%20-site:shutterstock.com%20-site:depositphotos.com%20-site:123rf.com%20-site:alamy.com%20-site:ezcanvas.com%20-site:istockphoto.com%20-site:bigstockphoto.com%20-site:vecteezy.com%20-site:adobe.stock.com%20-site:HQvectors.com%20-site:www.imagenesmy.com%20-site:vectorstock.com%20-site:creativemarket.com&rlz=1C5MACD_enFR506FR507&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi-uoj59NLhAhWxx4UKHfOZCqsQ_AUIDigB&biw=1908&bih=1200)

Image from [freepik.com](https://www.freepik.com/free-vector/abstract-white-poly-background_1276635.htm)
[image]

Image from [freedesignfile.com](https://freedesignfile.com/292028-white-geometric-shapes-backgrounds-vector-set-12/)
[image]

Image from [freedesignfile.com](https://freedesignfile.com/292019-white-geometric-shapes-backgrounds-vector-set-09/)
[image]