# Is there a name for the type of design that's a bunch of 3D triangles of similar shade?

Tags: shapes, 3d, terminology, style-identification

Usually see it in SVGs, either 2D or 3D.  I really like the design, but not sure what it's called.

Something like this: https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/images/polymer1.0-01.svg

Or even the banner background here: http://snapsvg.io/ http://snapsvg.io/assets/images/background.svg

Would like to create some of these myself in Illustrator!

Comment: Related: [tools to create this](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/10656/23061)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This effect is referred to as "low-poly." The name comes from 3D models with a low number of polygons. [Search for low poly](https://www.google.com/search?q=low%20poly&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&hl=en&client=safari) and you will find a lot of examples, tutorials, etc. as this style has been somewhat in vogue lately.

Comment: Related: delaunay triangulation

Comment: @allcaps thank you, and +1 (would like, but im not at 15 yet :( )