# Get the average color of a raster image for a mosaic effect

Tags: color, cs6, javascript, raster, cc-2017

I've been searching for a way to get the average color of a raster image, to use in a vector grid in front of it to create a mosaic effect - the "Object > Create Object Mosaic..." menu option does not provide enough flexibility to get the effect I want.

Basically, I'd like to do this:

[image: low polygon apple vector]

(*source*: http://vectorboom.com/load/tutorials/effects/polygonal_vector_mosaic/3-1-0-305)

It seems like Scriptographer would have been PERFECT for what I'm trying to do, but it is only supported up to CS5, and I'm on CC. I've looked into Paper.js (the sort of...evolution of Scriptographer), but cannot figure out how to implement it into Illustrator.

Does anyone know how to use Paper.js with Illustrator? And, more specifically, has anyone had any success with Paper.js in creating an effect similar to the one I posted above?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Turn image into geometric array of colours](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/10656/turn-image-into-geometric-array-of-colours) Use the raster tools, then trace in AI. In addition, a Google search quickly turns up [**this**](https://blogging.com/low-poly-generators/).

Comment: You dont use paper js in illustrator. Noncompatible api between browser and illustrator. Neither scriptographer nor illustrator scripting api have any hooks for querrying values from raster images.

Comment: Sorry, I am not quite clear, what you are asking. Do you need to get the average color of an entire raster image? Or do you need to create a mosaic effect in illustrator? The sample graphic you're showing is most likely done via low-poly modelling in an 3D application.

Answer (score 0):

In Illustrator CC you can double click on the Eyedropper tool to open the Options, and change it from point sample to either 3x3 or 5x5 average.

[image]